# How to print PHP file contents in PHP?

Tags: php

Since I am new to PHP I want to know how to print a file content in PHP?
Actually my project consist of form from which data is choosed to print on a report but I want a print button on my form to print the report contents directly. Can anyone help please?
Here's my code .. I have used CSS, html and PHP and it has two buttons view and print

```
<?php
       if ($_POST["submit"] == "View") {
?>      
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <head>
                <style type="text/css" media="all">
                    * {
                        margin:0px;
                        padding:0;
                    }
                    body {
                        margin:0px;
                        padding:0px;
                        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        font-size:12px;
                    }

                    span {
                        font-size:12px;
                    }

                    th, td {
                        width: 100mm;
                        height: 33.5mm;
                    }
                    table {
                        border-collapse:collapse;
                    }
                </style>
                <title>Hotel Label -  <?php echo $_SESSION["tourname"]; ?></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="margin:0px; padding:0; width:210mm; margin-top:12mm; margin-bottom:12mm; margin-left:0.5cm; margin-right:0cm; ">
<?php
        //echo $getno;
   /* } // View Tag Close
    else {

         ini_set("memory_limit", "50M");
         ob_start();*/

?>
            <style type="text/css" media="all">
                <!--
                body {
                    margin:0px;
                    font-family:Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size:12px;
                }

                span {
                    font-size:12px;
                }

                td {
                    width: 100mm;
                    max-width: 100mm;
                    height: 33.5mm;
                    max-height:33.5mm;
                    top:0mm;
                }
                table {
                    border-collapse:collapse;
                }
                -->
            </style>
            <page backtop="13mm" backbottom="1mm" backleft="5mm" backright="5mm" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana;">
<?php

?>
                <?php

                $ctr16 = 0;
                $ctr16_2 = 0;
                $nctr = 0;
                $ctr = 0;
                $mctr = 0;
                $lblctr = 0;
                while ($lbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                    $ctr16++;
                    $ctr16_2++;
                    $nctr++;
                    $ctr++;
                    $lblctr++;
                    $getno--;

                    if ($ctr == 1) {
                        echo "<table border=\"0\" align=\"left\" style =\"width: 210mm;\">";
                        echo "\n <tr> \n ";
                        echo "\n <tr> \n ";
                        echo "\n <td style=\"width: 100mm; max-width: 100mm; height:33.5mm; padding-left:1mm;\" valign=\"top\"> \n";

                        if ($lblctr > 16) {
                         echo "<br>";
                         echo "<br>";
                        $lblctr = 1;
                    }

                    if ($ctr16 > 64) {
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        $ctr16 = 1;
                    }

                    }
                    else {
                        echo "\n <td style=\"width: 100mm; max-width: 100mm; height:33.5mm; padding-left:15mm;\" valign=\"top\"> \n";
                        if ($nctr > 16) {
                         echo "<br>";
                         echo "<br>";
                         $nctr = 1;
                    }
                    if ($ctr16_2 > 64) {
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        $ctr16_2 = 1;
                    }

                    }
                    echo "<br />". "<span><font size='3px'><b>$lbl[hotelname]</b></font>";
// echo "<font size='2px'>$lbl[hotelname]";

echo "<br />"."<br />"."<font size='2px'>Haji No.-$lbl[hajino]</font>";
echo "<br />"."$lbl[suffix] $lbl[surname] $lbl[name]$lbl[midname] <br />";

echo "<br />"."<font size='2px'><b>Room No - $lbl[roomno] &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Bus No - $lbl[busname]</font></b>";
echo "<br />";

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "</span> ";

                   // echo "<br />";
                    echo "</td>";
                    if ($ctr == 2 || $getno == 0) {
                    echo '<br />';
                    $ctr = 0;
                    echo "</table>";

                    }
                }
                mysql_free_result($get);
                ?>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
  <?php

 } else($_POST["submit"]== "Print"){

     $filecontents = file_get_contents("hotel_label_print.php");
     print $filecontents;
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents()` 
(http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: but how?? i tried that but its nt working

Comment: Be more specific please. What do mean under `not working`? Did you check file permissions? It is a common mistake.

Comment: no i mean to say dt whn i press the print button it shows the code rather then printing that page

Comment: @daedalus i posted the report's code above shud i post the form's code too?

Comment: @yaser I didn't ask for that code.  I asked for the code where you used file_get_contents and it failed.  That is not what is above.  Please post it.  Also, please use whole words.

Comment: i did posted the edited code above please help me out

Comment: You are printing a PHP file so it is normal that you get a 'code' instead of the report itself. You need the output of the script that generates the report, not the script. You can try including that PHP file in the code above and use ob_start() and ob_end_clean().

Comment: where to add ob_start() and where to end it pls help me

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: can u please edit my code and show me please